# Angular language service >12 is not working on HTML files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ionic4, vscode-extensions

Thought this might be useful to others who are struggling to get angular language service work on HTML files.

Angular language service doesn't work on HTML files if the extension version is more than 12.
[image: autocomplete suggestion when extension version is 11.2.14]

[image: extension version 12.0.3 and not autocomplete sugesstion come up]

Anyone knows how to get it to work in the latest plugin? What changed from 11 to 12?

**ng version details**

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.13
Node: 14.15.1
OS: win32 x64
```

Comment: For me this only works using the "Use legacy view engine language service" option. (in the Extension Settings). I also would like to know how to get this working without this option.

Comment: Hello there... did you figure why it does not work? I guess that the only sotution is to downgrade to a previous version

Comment: Yea.. As of not downgrade is the only option.